# refreshing a page posting old eventargument

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

I do a postback on the client below. The sender is a button with the ID "cmdPrivate" and then my parameter - item_sources.

The problem I am having is that after this, if the user clicks the refresh button or hits F5, it posts back the last __EVENTARGUMENT and __EVENTTARGET I used even though this function is not called directly. What can I do to make sure this target and argument are cleared and not posted back everytime the user clicks refresh?

```
__doPostBack("cmdPrivate", item_sources)
```

Comment: you can do redirect to self

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net issue with F5 after postback, because it does what it should](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142740/asp-net-issue-with-f5-after-postback-because-it-does-what-it-should)

Comment: I am trying to maintain a page navigation menu state using eventArgument and eventTarget, I suppose this is using it outside of what it is intended to do. The link you provided does backup my hunch. I will have to find a better way. Thanks for your time.